# how to collect get urls and move to detailed link data using python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to scrape several links and collect specific information belonging to each site.

I think I need to use for loop for this. This is the code that I wrote.
In this case, I could get only one result, but I need all results.
I want to know how to back to URL parts and work again till I find all results.

```
# collect urls

data = html.select("div.content a")
for i in data:
    url = "wwww...." + i["href"]

# move to url link and collect specific information

raw_each = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
html_each = BeautifulSoup(raw_each.text,'html.parser')
reply = html_each.select("div.content td")
print(reply[14].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constantly overwrite the value of `url` with the next link in your list.
If you want to keep all the links, you will have to store them in an object that can hold multiple links, such as a list:

```
data = html.select("div.content a")
urls = []
for i in data:
    urls.append("wwww...." + i["href"])
```

This produces a list of links you can iterate over in the next step.